# FullCalendar - Handle Double click event

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar and on click of particular time cell I am opening up a colorbox , problem is happening when user double clicks the same cell which leads to same page appearing twice in colorbox.

Output of below code when executed in chrome and double clicked on particular time is -

day click happened
selection is made
day click happened
selection is made

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: ''
        },
        height: 500,
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        minTime: 0,
        firstHour : 9,
        maxTime: 24,
        firstDay : 1,
        allDaySlot: false,
        axisFormat: 'H:mm',
        timeFormat: 'HH:mm{-HH:mm}',
        disableDragging: true,
        eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
          console.log('event clicked');
        },
        selectable: true,
        eventSources : [
                        {
                            url : '/XXX/yyyyy',
                            editable : true,
                            allDayDefault : false
                        }
        ],
        eventRender: function(event, element) {
             element.bind('dblclick', function() {         
                 console.log('dbl clicked');
             });
             element.draggable = false;
             event.editable = false;

        },
        select: function(start,end,title,jsEvent) {
            console.log('selection is made');
        } ,
        dayClick: function(start,end,event,element) {
            console.log('day click happened');
        },
        eventMouseover: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
             console.log('event mouse over');
        },
        eventMouseout: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
             console.log('event mouse out');        
        },

    });

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar();

    <div id='calendar'>
</div>
```

I am looking for solution to prevent double click.

Comment: Did you solve the issue? I've the same problem

Answer (score 2):

Upon opening you could check if the page is already opened and ignore that click when this holds true. When closing the page you need to reset the open state so you can open something else. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Mo....I want to prevent before opening page..i created below solution working       if(dttime!=0){
     dttime=0;
     return;
    }
 dayClick: function(start,end,event,element) {
    var sd = new Date(start);
    var ed = new Date(end);
    var x = sd.getTime();
    var y = map[x];
    if(typeof(y)=='undefined'){
     y = 'clicked';
     map[x] = 'clicked';
    } else {
     dttime = x;
    } 
   },

Comment: Above solution fails,when user clicks triple, four, five....click continuously. I am looking for disabling the cell when first click happens.Is it achievable ?

Comment: Yeah sure. You could remove the click handler from the component once it is activated and add it again after the opened element is closed again.